# How to paste several FILENAME in a template in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a template A.tsv (field separator =\t) :

```
Name    data
```

And several file , for example B.txt and C.txt.

I want to print the filename in the filename (but in a new file) like this :

```
Name    data
B
C
```

I've done this :

```
template="A.tsv"
for bla in data/*.txt ; do
r="$(basename -s ".txt" $bla)"
( head -n 1 $template
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" -v filename=$r '{print filename}' $bla ) > test_name.tsv  ;
done
```

But it give me :

```
Name    data
C
C
C
C
C
C
C
```

Do you have a clue on wht's wrong with my command ?

Thanks

Comment: `awk` will execute your command once per line of the file. So you repeatedly make `awk` print the variable `$r`, hence the many "C"s. Why do you use `awk` in the first place? Use `>> file` to append output to a file (where `> file` would overwrite the file) and directly write `basename`'s results.

Comment: I did'nt fully understand your solution ? What can I change aside from `>` to `>>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script with detailed comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

#using the template variable is redundant, but
#I assume you want to use that lateron
template="A.tsv"
#write header from template and create file "output.txt"
#overwrites old version of "output.txt" if existing
head -n 1 ${template} > output.txt

#loop over files:
for bla in data/*.txt ; do
   #get basename without file suffix, add result to "output.txt" 
   basename -s ".txt" ${bla} >> output.txt
done
```

Note that you should prefer using `${variable}` or `"$varaible"`, especially for filenames, otherwise the script will break in case of files with e.g. spaces in the name.

---

**Why did the `awk`-approach fail?**

`awk` runs on a per-line basis. Your code had this:

```
awk -v variable=$r '{print variable}' ${file}
```

So when you have a file with 10 lines, the above command will be executed 10 times and result in 10 lines of the variable. For stopping `awk` after one run, use `exit` or specify a line where the command should be executed:

```
#execute command only on line no. 1
awk 'NR == 1 { print $1 }' file
#execute command and quit awk
awk '{ print 1 ; exit }'
```

**Where else did the original script fail?**

`>>` will append the output to a file, where `>` overwrites it. In your script you had a loop with this content:

```
( head -n 1 $template
awk [...] $bla ) > test_name.tsv
```

What happened is that for every match in `data/*txt`, this command would run, thus overwriting previous versions of `test_name.tsv` and leaving you with the last run only. Note how you also rewrote the header in every run of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and for the detail on what I was wrong !